# Using Polymorphism through WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, polymorphism

I'm trying to send a `List<Items>` through a WCF client using Polymorpishm. This is not working for me at the moment.

#### Problem

I'm using SOAP-UI to test my exposed Methods, I get **no result** returned.

#### The Question

How do I properly expose my classes in the "Object" (My guess this is the problem, could be wrong).

#### Code

The class which implements my interface:

```
public class ItemCreator : IItemCreator
{
  public ResponseObject GetItems()
  {
    return new ResponseObject
    {
      Obj = Item.GenerateItems() //Returns a List of Items: List<Item>
    };
  }
}
```

#### The Interface IItemCreator

```
[ServiceContract]
public Interface IItemCreator
{
   [OperationContract]
   ResponseObject GetItems();
}
```

#### The ResponseObject

```
 [DataContract()]
 [KnownType(typeof(Item))]
 public class ResponseObject
 {
    [DataMember]
    public object Obj;
 }
```

**Items Class**

```
public class Item
{
 public List<Item> GenerateItems()
 {
  return new List<Item>();
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the definition for ResponseObject.

Comment: Also definition for Items would help. Additionally why do you use the object type and not simply Array or List ?

Comment: Since the object is nto alway of type IEnumerable

Comment: Want to be flexible on what to add to the ResponseObject

Comment: I just made up some code relevant to mine. this is not the actual code but same implementation

Comment: Well this isn't really runnable since a static class can't be used as a type parameter. Maybe you mean `Item` not `Items` in some of those places. I think the attribute actually has to be `[KnownType(typeof(List<Items>))]` since Obj is actually going to be a list.

Comment: Can you Post answer so i can accept?